# Spacing between a special character and text

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

Why do I get output like this ?

Why is the alignment varying if I embed the special characters like lambda and eta ?

**code sample 1:**

```
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:Highest spatial frequency}
\frac{2 \text{ }\eta \text{ }\sin (\alpha )}{\lambda }\\
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{aligned}
&\lambda \text{is the wavelength of the monochromatic light used}\\
&\eta \text{refers to the refractive index of the immersion fluid}\\
&\alpha \text{acceptance angle of the objective}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}
```

output:

[image: 1]

and ,

**code snippet 2:**

```
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:Highest spatial frequency}
\frac{2 \text{ }\eta \text{ }\sin (\alpha )}{\lambda }\\
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{aligned}
&$\lambda$ \text{is the wavelength of the monochromatic light used}\\
&$\eta$ \text{refers to the refractive index of the immersion fluid}\\
&$\alpha$ \text{acceptance angle of the objective}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}
```

Output:
[image: 2]

Comment: In math mode spacing is determined by TeX. If you want a space you should leave on at _within_ the start and end of the `\text{}` macro.  So it should be `\text{ is the wavelength of the monochromatic light used}`

Comment: The second example should give you a bunch of error messages as you are already inside a math environment and then switch back to text with `$` but then use a math-mode-only command (the Greek letters). The following space (between the second `$` and `\text`) is in fact in text-mode and thus shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spacing in math mode is controlled by TeX. If you want spacing between the math and text you should leave a space *within* the `text{}` macro:

[image]

### Notes:

- You should *not* be using `\text{ }` to add space in math mode.
  There is a reason why TeX produces the spacing it does in math mode. For instance look at the output produced by `$-x-y$`, and you will notice a different amount of spacing between the unary "negative" and the binary "minus" operator.
- Not sure how you are getting your second example to compile, as it does not compile for me.  One of the reasons why it is always best to post a fully compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:Highest spatial frequency}
\frac{2 \eta \sin (\alpha)}{\lambda }\\
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{aligned}
&\lambda \text{ is the wavelength of the monochromatic light used}\\
&\eta \text{ refers to the refractive index of the immersion fluid}\\
&\alpha \text{ acceptance angle of the objective}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``&\text{$\lambda$ is the ...}\\`` is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and another way it can be done which I just figured out is the below 
(by using ~ ) :

```
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:Highest spatial frequency}
%f_c=\frac{2. \eta \text{ } .(  \text{Sin($\alpha$)})}{\lambda }\\
\frac{2 \text{ }\eta \text{ }\sin (\alpha )}{\lambda }\\
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{aligned}
    &\lambda ~\text{is the wavelength of the monochromatic light used}\\
    &\eta ~\text{refers to the refractive index of the immersion fluid}\\
    &\alpha ~\text{acceptance angle of the objective}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}
```

[image: image1]

Comment: Don't type `2\text{ }\eta\text{ }\sin`: the output is wrong. A thin space will automatically appear between 'eta' and 'sin', but no space is wanted between '2' and 'eta'.